# moving from MSSQL to SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

An earlier thread brought me to the realization that we should consider moving to SQLSRV drivers for security and the ability to use parametized queries,
 more importantly in the short term I need this in my PHP (primarily so I don't have to escape quotes) for a new site being set up.
As our server has several sites, using MSSQL extensions and it will be a long term project to move these all over,
 I wanted to clarify if we are able to use both mssql / sqlsrv at the same time on the one server and gradually move over the sites one at a time. 
If you haven't guessed already by the wording of my question, I am still a little new to this and did not even know about server drivers until this morning.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL Server Drivers for PHP is an extension separate to the deprecated MSSql extension. As long as they're both activated in your php.ini file, there's no reason you can't use both. But I would suggest you test this out on a local server before you introduce it to a live environment. Logically though, it shouldn't make a difference.